# How to logging into remote iis8 server?

Tags: windows, server, webserver, iis-8

Our webhosting provide us a Windows server (probably iis8). I can upload the web content via FTP. But how do I log into the web server for management to make some setting changes to the server? I am using Windows 7 as the local client.

Comment: Ask the hosting service provider.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to connect iis 8 from the Windows 7 machine iis then it is not possible. windows 7 is client os and it does not support remote management feature. to use this feature you need to use server OS.